# How to retrieve data from CK Editor in corona sdk?

Tags: javascript, java, android, lua, coronasdk

I have embedded the CK Editor in a html page. Now I am not able to access the data's that are typed in the CK Editor's text area in my lua code. Is there any way to retrieve the data in corona ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant do this directly as Corona Webview has limited methods. However, you can make an HTTP call and separate the data yourself (is that editor data comes with the call). I have done this to other website to get currency prices. You can see below how I make a call to moneymex website and then separate the strings based on the pattern I know exists.

```
  secondField = display.newText( "Touch to Start", 155, 155, native.systemFontBold, 16 )
secondField:setFillColor( 1 )

local function networkListener( event )
      --local alert = native.showAlert( "Corona", "Crap", { "OK"} )
    if ( event.isError ) then
           local alert = native.showAlert( "Corona", event.response, { "OK"} )
    else
    local pattern = ">%d%d,%d%d%d<"
    local buyPrice = string.sub(event.response, string.find(event.response, pattern))
      -- local alert = native.showAlert( "Corona", string.sub(buyPrice, 2, -2), { "OK"} )
      local junkLength = string.len(event.response);
      local sellJunk = string.find(event.response, pattern)
        local  sellPriceJunk= string.sub(event.response, sellJunk+50, sellJunk-junkLength+1000)
        local sellPrice = string.sub(sellPriceJunk, string.find(sellPriceJunk, pattern))
secondField.text = string.sub(buyPrice,2,-2).." and "..string.sub(sellPrice,2,-2)

   local alert = native.showAlert( "Corona", string.sub(buyPrice,2,-2).." and "..string.sub(sellPrice,2,-2), { "OK"} )

end
end

network.request( "https://moneymex.com/Home/Welcome", "GET", networkListener )
```

Comment: Hello Amir, Thank you so much for the response that you have given me.It would be very grateful if you share a link regarding the idea that you have given.

Comment: just added the code, just copy that to your main.lua and it should work.