# In Corona sdk how do I manipulate the DOM of a web page before displaying the a page in a web view?

Tags: html, dom, lua, coronasdk

In Corona you are able to display a webpage in a web view using the url. I am unsure how to manipulate the DOM of the page before displaying it in the web view.

```
local webView = native.newWebView( display.contentCenterX,display.contentCenterY, 320, 480 )

webView:request( "http://www.coronalabs.com/" )
-- or
webView:request( "localfile.html", system.ResourceDirectory )
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get the response from a web page  as a string. You can manipulate and save the file and do whatever you need to do. Look ay this example where I separated the substring I needed:
[How to retrieve data from CK Editor in corona sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37299538/how-to-retrieve-data-from-ck-editor-in-corona-sdk/37339305?noredirect=1#comment62201485_37339305)

Then use this tutorial to open/create the file and change the content:
https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/data/readWriteFiles/index.html